# Numbering and naming a disubstituted cyclohexene

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I saw this cyclohexene in my textbook and wonder why it’s like that. I searched the internet and it’s correct but why?
As I know we try to keep the numbers low, so instead of 1,6-dichlorocyclohexene we can tell 2,3-dichlorocyclohexene and the numbers are lower. I appreciate your help.

[image: 1,6-dichlorocyclohex-1-ene]

Comment: @IvanNeretin is it the same for 3-brumo 1,4,6 cyclohepta tri en and 7-brumo 1,3,5 cyclohepta tri en? How can i determine such things in my exams actually ? Im a little bit confused